# What's the difference between a worker thread and an I/O thread?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, web-config, processmodel

Looking at the processmodel element in the Web.Config there are two attributes.

```
maxWorkerThreads="25" 
maxIoThreads="25"
```

What is the difference between worker threads and I/O threads?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fundamentally not a lot, it's all about how ASP.NET and IIS allocate I/O wait objects and manage the contention and latency of communicating over the network and transferring data.

I/O threads are set aside as such because they will be doing I/O (as the name implies) and may have to wait for "long" periods of time (hundreds of milliseconds).  They also can be optimized and used differently to take advantage of I/O completion port functionality in the Windows kernel.  A single I/O thread may be managing multiple completion ports to maintain throughput.

Windows has a lot of capabilities for dealing with I/O blocking whereas ASP.NET/.NET has a plain concept of "Thread".  ASP.NET can optimize for I/O by using more of the unmanaged threading capabilities in the OS. You wouldn't want to do this all the time for every thread as you lose a lot of capabilities that .NET gives you which is why there is a distinction between how the threads are intended to be used.

Worker threads are threads upon which regular "work" or just plain code/processing happens.  Worker threads are unlikely to block a lot or wait on anything and will be short running and therefore require more aggressive scheduling to maximize processing power and throughput.

[Edit]: I also found this link which is particularly relevant to this question:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericeil/archive/2008/06/20/windows-i-o-threads-vs-managed-i-o-threads.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Just to add on to chadmyers...
Seems like I/O Threads was the old way ASP.NET serviced requests,

> "Requests in IIS 5.0 are typically
>   serviced over I/O threads, or threads
>   performing asynchronous I/O because
>   requests are dispatched to the worker
>   process using asynchronous writes to a
>   named pipe."

with IIS6.0 this has changed.

> "Thus all requests are now serviced by
>   worker threads drawn from the CLR
>   thread pool and never on I/O threads."

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc164128(en-us).aspx