# ASP.NET Performance: Worker Threads and I/O Threads

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

**Duplicate of:** [What’s the difference between a worker thread and an I/O thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137400/whats-the-difference-between-a-worker-thread-and-an-i-o-thread)

What is the difference between an I/O thread and an Worker thread in IIS/ASP.NET?  How do these concepts affect the design of an ASP.NET app?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137400/whats-the-difference-between-a-worker-thread-and-an-i-o-thread

Answer (score 1):

Please see [What’s the difference between a worker thread and an I/O thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137400/whats-the-difference-between-a-worker-thread-and-an-i-o-thread)