# Does every 'HttpRequest' get its own thread in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, httprequest

In ASP.NET, does every `HttpRequest` get its own thread?

***Update*** - To clarify, I'm asking specifically about incoming requests.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you're referring to using the HttpRequest object for making outgoing requests from your application, no - HttpRequest runs in the current thread.

If you're referring to how IIS and ASP.NET handles threading per request, yes. Each request is run on a separate thread. However, the model is a little more complex than that - there are [worker threads and I/O threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137400/whats-the-difference-between-a-worker-thread-and-an-i-o-thread/137431#137431) to consider. And under load, .NET will sometimes move requests [from one thread to another](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/11/threadstatic-callcontext-and_02.html) as it sees fit. This is important to understand when dealing with things like ThreadStatic.